# Правильная директива для установки Java из пакетного менеджера

Tags: java, debian

Стоит Debian. Что необходимо прописать, чтоб устанавливалась Java по:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jreа
```

не из исходников.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ apt-cache search openjdk-7-jre

java-package - Utility for creating Java Debian packagesopen
jdk-7-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-7-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-7-jre-lib - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
openjdk-7-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
```

Присутствует в дебиан сид.

Answer (score 1):

В Debian Вы также можете установить проприетарные JRE и JDK от Oracle.
Для этого необходимо воспользоваться утилитой `make-jpkg`, устанавливаемой из пакета `java-package`.

Эта утилита из тарболла (файла *.tar.gz), скачанного с [официального сайта Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), сформирует для Вас *.deb-пакет, который можно установить с помощью команды `dpkg -i`. Если захотите воспользоваться этой утилитой, имейте в виду, что скачанный с сайта архив не нужно переименовывать. По крайней мере, у меня *.deb-пакет не формировался, пока я не переименовал тарболл обратно.